Modify default NACL of pre-existing VPC
I'm trying to modify the default NACL of a pre-existing VPC in AWS.
I'm attempting to adapt/use the syntax from the doc, but I'm not having much success.
The VPC already exists (but was not created in/by Terraform).
I am attempting to reference the VPC ID by using a data resource type rather than the resource type shown in the doc.
My code looks like this:
    data "aws_vpc" "default" {
      id = "vpc-067415793148e22d1"
    }
    
    resource "aws_default_network_acl" "default" {
      default_network_acl_id = data.aws_vpc.default.default_network_acl.id
    
      egress {
        protocol   = "tcp"
        rule_no    = 80
        action     = "deny"
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        from_port  = 22
        to_port    = 22
      }
    
      ingress {
        protocol   = "tcp"
        rule_no    = 90
        action     = "deny"
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        from_port  = 3389
        to_port    = 3389
      }
    }

But Terraform does not like me trying to use a data reference whenn trying to get the default_network_acl_id value? It outputs:
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 39, in resource "aws_default_network_acl" "default":
│   39:   default_network_acl_id = data.aws_vpc.default.default_network_acl_id
│ 
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "default_network_acl_id".
╵

I'm a little bit stuck where to go from this. I understand if I was creating a resource "aws_vpc" "mainvpc" {} I would be able to reference that, but to get the VPC information as data from an existing VPC does not seem to be as strightforward?
Is what I am trying to do possible in this way?
Many thanks.

This attribute simply does not exist for the data source. It exists only for the resource. Why not create a new NACL and attach it to the VPC? If the issue is in the data source, why not import the VPC into terraform and then you'll be able to use the default NACL? Also, there is a note that the default NACL resource is a special resource, and care should be taken.

Data resource of aws_vpc does not return default nacl id. Fields of a sample vpc looks like
> data.aws_vpc.default
{
  "arn" = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:vpc/vpc-xxxxax4x"
  "cidr_block" = "172.31.0.0/16"
  "cidr_block_associations" = tolist([
    {
      "association_id" = "vpc-cidr-assoc-1a8c4771"
      "cidr_block" = "172.31.0.0/16"
      "state" = "associated"
    },
  ])
  "default" = true
  "dhcp_options_id" = "dopt-85xxxaef"
  "enable_dns_hostnames" = true
  "enable_dns_support" = true
  "enable_network_address_usage_metrics" = false
  "filter" = toset(null) /* of object */
  "id" = "vpc-xxxxx4x"
  "instance_tenancy" = "default"
  "ipv6_association_id" = ""
  "ipv6_cidr_block" = ""
  "main_route_table_id" = "rtb-xx2exx68"
  "owner_id" = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  "state" = tostring(null)
  "tags" = tomap({})
  "timeouts" = null /* object */
}

Only the way to get default nacl id is using aws_network_acls data resource with filter default as true value.
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
    id = "vpc-2951a943"
}

data "aws_network_acls" "default" {
    vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
    filter {
      name = "default"
      values = [true]
    }
}

resource "aws_default_network_acl" "default" {
    default_network_acl_id = data.aws_network_acls.default.ids[0]

    egress {
        protocol   = "tcp"
        rule_no    = 80
        action     = "deny"
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        from_port  = 22
        to_port    = 22
    }

    ingress {
        protocol   = "tcp"
        rule_no    = 90
        action     = "deny"
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        from_port  = 3389
        to_port    = 3389
    }
} 

